# where is the hold music file located on Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

would anyone know what the file name is (and the location) of the hold music file is in Asterisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my fairly old version of Asterisk, there's a config file named `musiconhold.conf`, you'll have to look into it to know where the file(s) is(are) located.

Comment: i will look into the file and see what i can find thanks for your help.

Comment: musiconhold.conf is correct, even for recent versions of asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Its under /etc/asterisk

Comment: yeah thats true

Comment: That is not true it is under /var/lib/asterisk/moh

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/asterisk/moh` is the default location. If you want to use your own custom music on hold you may configure that at `/etc/asterisk/musiconhold.conf`